# Touchpad buttons not working on Lenovo Yoga 2-11 with Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, elantech

I decided to install Ubuntu on my old Lenovo Yoga 2-11. It made a huge difference in terms of performance (compared to Windows), but there is one last annoying thing I can't fix. The buttons which are integrated in the lower part of the touchpad don't work. Any idea if it's possible to fix them?
I've tried using evemu-tools as suggested in other threads, but no luck.

Output of xinput -list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of xinput list-props 14

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (174):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (176): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (315): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (316): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (317):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (318):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (319):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (320):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (321):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (322):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (323):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (324):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (325):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (326):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (327):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (328):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (329):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (330): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (331):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (332):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (333):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (334):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (335): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (336): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (337): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (338): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (296): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (297):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (298):    0, 0
    Device Node (299):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (300):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (339):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (340):   1
```

Output of evemu-record

```
kitten@kitten-Yoga-2-11:~$ sudo evemu-record
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
/dev/input/event5:  Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer
/dev/input/event6:  Ideapad extra buttons
/dev/input/event7:  Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC
/dev/input/event8:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event9:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event11: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Select the device event number [0-12]:
```

Output after selecting device 4 and pressing the buttons (although I have the feeling evemu is detecting me touching the touchpad rather than me pressing the lower side of it where the buttons are)
[image: evemu output]

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong setting

```
Click Method Enabled (331):    0, 1
```

This setting means "buttonfinger"

The default setting is

```
Click Method Enabled Default (332):    1, 0
```

that sets to "buttonareas".

You've changed the default setting somewhere.

Run

```
 xinput set-prop 14 331 1 0
```

and test how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't make any difference :(